# loop through a python json object and count a NULL for level 3 if all the values in levels 4 and 5 are null

Tags: python, json, pandas, lambda, iterator

For a normal dataset, I would normally use this code to count nulls

```
dfGaps = df.groupby(df['IndexColumn'])[['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum())
```

But instead I have a DataFrame that normalizes a json object with 4 or 5 nested levels

With this code

```
normalize_json = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
for col in normalize_json.columns:
    print(col)
```

I have this output for which I need to count null values in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd levels:

```
url
id
rev
fields.System.AreaPath
fields.System.TeamProject
fields.System.IterationPath
fields.System.WorkItemType
fields.System.State
fields.System.Reason
fields.System.AssignedTo.displayName
fields.System.AssignedTo.url
fields.System.AssignedTo._links.avatar.href
fields.System.AssignedTo.id
fields.System.AssignedTo.uniqueName
fields.System.AssignedTo.imageUrl
fields.System.AssignedTo.descriptor
comment_version_ref.url
comment_version_ref.comment_id
comment_version_ref.version
```

If all the following fields are blank for a particular ID, then I want to count the null for **fields.System.AssignedTo** :

```
fields.System.AssignedTo.displayName
fields.System.AssignedTo.url
fields.System.AssignedTo._links.avatar.href
fields.System.AssignedTo.id
fields.System.AssignedTo.uniqueName
fields.System.AssignedTo.imageUrl
fields.System.AssignedTo.descriptor
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to subset the dataframe columns according to the specified labels.

Then use [`pandas.DataFrame.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to check `NaN` in dataframe.

```py
count = df.filter('AssignedTo', axis=1).isna().sum()
```